# Why finite field Kakeya problem is/was hard?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $F_q$ is a finite field of cardinality $q$ and $V$ is a vector space over $F_q$. The finite field Kakeya problem asks for a lower bound on the cardinality of a Kakeya set in $V$, which is a set that contains a line in every direction.

Intuitively, why is this problem a hard one?

A Kakeya set is equivalently a set that contains translates of 1-dimensional subspaces of $V$. We can easily calculate the number of 1-dim subspaces of V. I don't get why isn't this a lower bound.

Comment: Why would it be a lower bound? It's not (prima facie anyways) the case that each translated subspace needs to have a point not "used" by any other translated subspace.

Comment: The paper by [Dvir](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.2336.pdf) gives a good account on what is difficult about the finite field Kakeya problem.

Comment: I think the problem is on affine lines so this is why it is complicated